# Make extension for String

Tags: swift, string

I got homework and I can't handle it. What I need?
I have a project that uses two languages (English, Spanish). The project has 2 Locolizable.strings files for two languages.
Example string:

```
"OrderDetails_IPText" = "IP: %@";
```

I understand %@ is a string or some object, it does not matter. The problem is in people who help me with the translation of texts into different languages.
When they fill in the translation file, they see:

```
%@
```

They do not understand what I want to add there. This could be an email address or something else. People who translate the text gave me the task to implement a function that will take into account such nuances. They even offered some implementation, something like this:

```
func pffffff(format: something, ["key" : value] -> Id : value
```

Probably it should be an extension for String.
If you do not understand, thanks for watching this question. I did not understand anything.

We advised that you need to change this func:

```
func L (_ key: String, value: String = "") -> String
{
    let str = NSLocalizedString(key, value: value, comment: "")
    return str
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like this.

```
extension String {
   func yourFunction () {}
}
```

But I would recommend you not to use `%@` or any other character in localization string. You can always use replace string function with when the string contains any variable

For eg:
`"We have sent an OTP at [VARIABLEA]"`

Then while displaying just look for `[VARIABLEA]` and replace with actual value

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out of this situation.

```
public extension String {

/* Creates the string representation of the poo with requested size.
 - parameter format: string format with key
 - returns: localizable string
 */
public init(format: String, keyArguments: [String: Any]) {
    self = format
    keyArguments.forEach {
        self = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "{\($0.key)}", with: "\($0.value)", options: .caseInsensitive)
    }
}
```

}

Was:

```
let asd = String(format: "Hi, %@! %d", "Arnold", 2)
```

Now:

```
let str = String(format: "Hi, {User_Name}! How are you, {user_name}?", keyArguments: ["user_name" : "Arnold", "number": 5.6])
```